# retrieve SNP location in biomaRt, command hangs

Tags: r, biomart

I was trying to retrieve information on a SNP location. I tried to follow the instructions of an answer from this website, but the command doesn't work anymore:

```
library(biomaRt) # biomaRt_2.30.0

snp_mart = useMart("ENSEMBL_MART_SNP", dataset="hsapiens_snp")

snp_ids = c("rs16828074", "rs17232800")
snp_attributes = c("refsnp_id", "chr_name", "chrom_start")

snp_locations = getBM(attributes=snp_attributes, filters="snp_filter", 
                      values=snp_ids, mart=snp_mart)
```

I get the following error after waiting for a long time:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Request to BioMart web service failed. Verify if you are still connected to the internet.  Alternatively the BioMart web service is temporarily down.
```

Did anything change in biomaRt commands since the last version? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe the service is down as the message says?

Comment: This has been going for weeks, and the server website seems to be working fine (http://www.ensembl.org/). And all the other datasets in the same server seem to be working (gene, protein, etc). This problem is only with the SNP dataset, exactly the one I need.

Comment: I get the same error right now. Try contacting helpdesk@ensembl.org, they are pretty helpful.

Comment: Thanks! For now I found a workaround for it by using an older ensembl archive as host. But I will contact them for sure.

Answer (score 3):

This is more like a workaround then a definitive answer to this problem.
But now Ensembl is in its version 90. If I use an archived host from the previous version (v89, from http://may2017.archive.ensembl.org), the SNP datasets is working again. So here is my temporary solution while v90 is not working for SNPs:

```
library("biomaRt")
snp_mart = useMart(biomart = "ENSEMBL_MART_SNP", dataset="hsapiens_snp", host='may2017.archive.ensembl.org')

snp_ids = c("rs16828074", "rs17232800")

snp_attributes = c("refsnp_id", "chr_name", "chrom_start")

snp_locations = getBM(attributes=snp_attributes, filters="snp_filter", 
                       values=snp_ids, mart=snp_mart)
```

The result should look like this:

```
snp_locations
   refsnp_id chr_name chrom_start
1 rs16828074        2   231454043
2 rs17232800       18    68625022
```